# Why does array output work twice? Why is there more than one space between words in the output?

Tags: perl

I have an anagram function, which receives a reference to an array of words as input. The function must return a hash, the keys of which are the first found words from the set of anagrams, the values must be references to an array, each element of which is a word from the set, in the order in which it was first encountered in the dictionary. Identical words from the set should be removed, all words should be reduced to the same case.

Sample input:

```
abc
BAc
BOOk
cab
one
Noe
rory
eon 
Yror
rrYo
Koob
BoKo
ooKB 
book
abc
```

Sample output:

```
abc,bac,book,cab,one,noe,rory,eon,yror,rryo,koob,boko,ookb,book,abc
abc,bac,book,cab,one,noe,rory,eon,yror,rryo,koob,boko,ookb
abc: abc bac cab
book: book koob boko ookb
one: one noe eon
rory: rory yror rryo
```

My script:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use utf8;
no warnings;
use 5.10.0;

my @list = qw(abc BAc BOOk cab one Noe rory eon Yror rrYo Koob BoKo ooKB book abc);

sub anagram {
    my $arrayref = shift;
    my $index = 0;
    my @array;
    my @uniq;
    my @match;
    my %hash;
    my %uniq = ();
    for (my $i = 0; $i < $#$arrayref; $i++ ) {
        push @array, lc(@$arrayref[$i]);
    }
    say join ",", @array;
    @uniq = grep { !$uniq{$_}++ } @array;
    say join ",", @uniq;
    while (@uniq) {
        my @chars = split(//, @uniq[0]);
        my @indexes;
        my $regex = "[";
        for (my $i = 0; $i < scalar @chars; $i++) {
            $regex = $regex . $chars[$i];
        }
        $regex = $regex . "]{" . scalar @chars . "}";
        for (my $i = 0; $i < scalar @uniq; $i++) {
            if ($uniq[$i] =~ m/$regex/) {
               push @indexes, $i;
               $match[$index][$i] = $uniq[$i];
            }
        }
        $hash{$uniq[0]} = $match[$index];
        my $last_index = $#indexes;
        for (my $i = $last_index; $i >= 0; $i--) {
            splice @uniq, $indexes[$i], 1;
        }
        @indexes = ();
        $index++;
    }
    return \%hash;
}

anagram(\@list);
my $result = anagram(\@list);
say "$_: @{$result->{$_}}" for sort keys %$result;
```

My output:

```
abc,bac,book,cab,one,noe,rory,eon,yror,rryo,koob,boko,ookb,book
abc,bac,book,cab,one,noe,rory,eon,yror,rryo,koob,boko,ookb
abc,bac,book,cab,one,noe,rory,eon,yror,rryo,koob,boko,ookb,book
abc,bac,book,cab,one,noe,rory,eon,yror,rryo,koob,boko,ookb
abc: abc bac  cab
book: book       koob boko ookb
one: one noe  eon
rory: rory yror rryo
```

1. Why are the contents of the arrays displayed twice?

```
    21      say join ",", @array;
    23      say join ",", @uniq;
```

My output:

```
abc,bac,book,cab,one,noe,rory,eon,yror,rryo,koob,boko,ookb,book
abc,bac,book,cab,one,noe,rory,eon,yror,rryo,koob,boko,ookb
abc,bac,book,cab,one,noe,rory,eon,yror,rryo,koob,boko,ookb,book
abc,bac,book,cab,one,noe,rory,eon,yror,rryo,koob,boko,ookb
```

Expected output:

```
abc,bac,book,cab,one,noe,rory,eon,yror,rryo,koob,boko,ookb,book,abc
abc,bac,book,cab,one,noe,rory,eon,yror,rryo,koob,boko,ookb
```

2. Why is there more than one space between words in my output?

```
abc: abc bac  cab
book: book       koob boko ookb
one: one noe  eon
rory: rory yror rryo
```

3. Why is the last word `abc` lost before deleting duplicates?

```
abc,bac,book,cab,one,noe,rory,eon,yror,rryo,koob,boko,ookb,book
abc,bac,book,cab,one,noe,rory,eon,yror,rryo,koob,boko,ookb
abc,bac,book,cab,one,noe,rory,eon,yror,rryo,koob,boko,ookb,book
abc,bac,book,cab,one,noe,rory,eon,yror,rryo,koob,boko,ookb
```

Comment: `no warnings` is a very bad thing to use. It does not make your errors and mistakes go away, it just makes them invisible, so they are harder to find.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. Why are the contents of the arrays displayed twice?

That's because they're printed - using `say()` - in your `anagram()` subroutine and you call that subroutine twice.

> 2. Why is there more than one space between words in my output?

If you use [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) to display the contents of `$result` when it is returned from `anagram()`, you'll see it looks like this:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'book' => [
                      'book',
                      undef,
                      undef,
                      undef,
                      undef,
                      undef,
                      undef,
                      'koob',
                      'boko',
                      'ookb'
                    ],
          'rory' => [
                      'rory',
                      'yror',
                      'rryo'
                    ],
          'one' => [
                     'one',
                     'noe',
                     undef,
                     'eon'
                   ],
          'abc' => [
                     'abc',
                     'bac',
                     undef,
                     'cab'
                   ]
        };
```

It looks like the `undef` values correspond with the extra spaces in your output.

Maybe you should replace:

```
say "$_: @{$result->{$_}}" for sort keys %$result;
```

With:

```
say "$_: ", join ' ', grep { defined } @{$result->{$_}}
  for sort keys %$result;
```

> 3. Why is the last word abc lost before deleting duplicates?

You have four `for` loops in your code. And you use three different approaches to writing those loops.

```
for (my $i = 0; $i < $#$arrayref; $i++ )

for (my $i = 0; $i < scalar @chars; $i++)

for (my $i = 0; $i < scalar @uniq; $i++)

my $last_index = $#indexes;
for (my $i = $last_index; $i >= 0; $i--)
```

The last three loops work as you expect them to (but they're all rather over-complicated for what you're trying to do). The first one, however, is causing your problem.

You seem to realise that `$#arrayname` gives the last index in an array (you use that in your first and last loops). But your first loop seems to have an "off-by-one" error. You stop iterating over the loop when `$i` is no longer less than `$#$arrayref`. This omits the last element of the array - and I don't think you meant to do that. If you replace your first loop with:

```
for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#$arrayref; $i++ ) # Note: >= instead of >
```

then you get the result you expect.

I expect you made this error because in other loops you use `@arrayname` rather than `$#arrayname`. But `@arrayname` gives you the **number** of elements in the array, not the last index. For any array, `@arrayname` will always be one more than `$#arrayname`.

You will rarely find Perl programmers using "C-style" `for` loops like yours. That's because they are very prone to exactly this kind of error. But, conveniently, we have the `foreach` style loop that is usually far simpler to understand. In this form, we simply generate a list of values and iterate across that list. If you're walking an array and need its index values, I'd always recommend `$#arrayname` over `@arrayname`.

Your four loops can be rewritten as:

```
foreach my $i (0 .. $#$arrayref)

foreach my $i (0 .. $#chars)

foreach my $i (0 .. $#uniq)

# This is slightly harder as we need the
# indexes in reverse order. So use "reverse()".
foreach my $i (reverse 0 .. $indexes)
```

In some cases, you're only using `$i` to access the elements of the array. In these cases, it's simpler still to just iterate over the list itself, rather than the indexes. For example, your first loop is:

```
for (my $i = 0; $i < $#$arrayref; $i++ ) {
    push @array, lc(@$arrayref[$i]);
}
```

That's better written as:

```
for my $el (@$arrayref) {
  push @array, lc $el;
}
```

Or even (as `@array` starts off empty):

```
my @array = map { lc } @$arrayref;
```

But I accept that's getting into some slightly esoteric Perl features :-)

**Update:** I notice that you have `no warnings` in your code. You should always have warnings turned on when writing Perl code. With `use warnings` your code omits two warnings (one of them repeated several times).

> Scalar value @uniq[0] better written as $uniq[0] at anagram2 line 25.

You have:

```
my @chars = split(//, @uniq[0]);
```

Individual elements of an array are scalar values and should therefore be accessed using `$`, not `@`. This line should be:

```
my @chars = split(//, $uniq[0]);
```

> Use of uninitialized value in join or string at anagram2 line 51.

This is the problem with undefined values in `$result` that we discussed and fixed above.

It's always better to keep `use warnings` turned on and fix any problems it shows you.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Why are the contents of the arrays displayed twice?

```perl
anagram(\@list);
my $result = anagram(\@list);
```

> 2. Why is there more than one space between words in my output?

Due to empty elements in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Please investigate following code snippet for compliance with your problem.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my($words,$seen);

while( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    s/^\s+|\s+\z//;
    my $val = lc $_;
    my $key = join('', sort split('', $val));
    push @{$words->{$key}}, $val unless $seen->{$val}++;
}

printf "%-5s : %s\n", $words->{$_}[0], join(', ', @{$words->{$_}})
    for sort keys %{$words};

exit 0;

__DATA__
abc
BAc
BOOk
cab
one
Noe
rory
eon 
Yror
rrYo
Koob
BoKo
ooKB 
book
abc
```

Output

```
abc   : abc, bac, cab
book  : book, koob, boko, ookb
one   : one, noe, eon
rory  : rory, yror, rryo
```